# Subquery with two where clause

Tags: sql

I have the table testing(name,money) where I have to return a result where all of the money that is positive is total into deposit and the negative amounts will be withdraw. With the query below it says :"Subquery is only allowed to return a single column."

```
SELECT name, SUM(money) AS "deposit"
FROM testing
where money > 0 in
    (SELECT name, SUM(abs(money)) AS "withdraw"
    FROM testing
    where money < 0 )
GROUP BY name;
```

p.s: i tried without the "In" and it's not working too

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name, 
       SUM(case when money > 0 then money else 0 end) AS deposit,
       SUM(case when money < 0 then money else 0 end) AS withdraw
FROM testing
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: the withdraw should displayed as absolute value but it works

Comment: i just added the "abs" before case and it worked thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following SQL statement

```
SELECT name, SUM(money) AS "deposit"
FROM testing
where money > 0
AND money in
(
    SELECT SUM(abs(money)) AS "withdraw"
    FROM testing
    where money < 0 
)
GROUP BY name;
```

Let me know if it works! :)